# Button clickable area is visible even outside the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a submit button in a form end. I found that even while clicking outside the button  the entire row of div for button acts a button.

Is there any option in css for that?I can provide the code if you want..Thanks in advance

html:

```
<div id="submit">
            <div id="block">
            <button type="submit"  id="submit">Create</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

css:

```
button.submit-button {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 70px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Comment: It's probably something in your CSS. Show us your HTML, CSS and JS code so that we can help you.

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: Submit buttons, under normal circumstances, do not behave like that. We can't tell why yours is acting that way because you failed to supply a [mcve]. Make sure you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sure..will post the code

Comment: your `div` and `button` both having same `id` i.e, `id="submit"`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have kept button inside an `anchor tag` having `display:block` like Button1 from snippet.

Make it to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a href="#" style="display:block; background-color: yellow;">
    <button>
      button1
    </button>
  </a>
  <div>
  <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; background-color: yellow;">
    <button>
      button2
    </button>
  </a>
  </div>
  <button>
    button3
  </button>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

your `div` and `button` both having same `id` i.e, `id="submit"`. It might be because of that. Change one of those `id's`

Comment: I didn't use href

Comment: did you use `a` tag

Comment: you kept `button` inside `a` ?

Comment: your `div` and `button` both having same `id` i.e, `id="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

You may have a href element that is hasn't been ended or you may have the href element around the div not the button. It would be easier to answer with code but your button should look like;

```
<a href="Your Link"><button>Your Button</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an example in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/12/).

Go have a look at it and try removing css attribute: `display` from `#block` or change it to `inline` and see what happens.

The size of the blue area is determined by your `margin` and `padding` on the button.

What you are looking for is `display: inline-block;` in this simple [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/14/) you can see that the button is keeping his normal size while the `div #submit` is by default using the entire row.

And also i changed the selector of the button to `id="button"`

Check this sites out for more Info: [**w3s Display**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and [**w3s Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are having same id in div and button tag, you should change that first. and then your CSS would be

```
 #button{
font-size: 14px;
padding: 1px 2px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0px 70px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-radius: 1px;
}
```

I hope it will help you.